# Which file of Windows does contain the Folder options dialog box?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have Windows 7 Home Premium and I need to remove or hide some option from the list of options that is displayed on the View tab of the Folder options dialog box. Which file of Windows does contain the list? And can I alter it somehow for example with HEX editor and how exactly?

Comment: Your goals are not realistic, the folder dialog box, is baked into Windows Explorer itself, in cases like this you would replace the shell with somebody you can configure.

Comment: Which option do you want to remove? They're in the registry.

Comment: Editing the file itself is not realistic or practical. Every core Windows file is digitally signed to prevent modification and changes to it will break the digital signature. Once you modify the file Windows will detect the invalid signature and, at best, replace it with a known good copy. At worst you will have broken Explorer and need to restore the file yourself. In order to create a valid file to replace the original with you would need to break into Microsoft and steal their code signing certificate.

Comment: @w32sh, I need to remove the option "Show hidden files, folders, and drives"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder option settings are in this part of the registry.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder
```

Start Regedit.exe and go to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden
```

(Be sure to backup the key before clearing it out.)

Right-click `Hidden` and choose Delete.

That removes `Show hidden files, folders, and drives` from Folder Options - View tab.

Comment: Thanks. And I would be more thankful if you will upvote my question. Someone downvoted it while a similar question by the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491999/configure-windows-explorer-folder-options-through-powershell got 24 upvotes